# How to see my notes in Outlook grouped by my folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Microsoft changed Outlook UI again. Previously I had all my storages and subfolders, including mails, caledar items, notes and etc shown hierarchically at the left pane. Now it is broken. It shows email folders in email mode, but not notes. In notes mode it heaps all notes into nonsystematic unknown grouping.

How to see my note folders back?

Comment: If you have you opted for "Try the new Outlook", then undo this choice. The [Ask Woody](https://www.askwoody.com/newsletter/free-edition-copilot-is-here-sort-of/) article also has some advice on blocking this new version of Outlook.

Comment: No, I don't have new Outlook (knowing what they do, would never accept any "new" look of anything)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Outlook Classic client, folders and Notes are in the icon of More apps on the left side. You can use the shortcut ctrl+5 to quickly navigate to Notes.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: I can see notes, what I can't see -- is the folders inside notes

Comment: You can go to the View tab and click on the folder pane > normal. You should then be able to see the Notes folder and any subfolders that you have created.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault. In an updated version it is still possible to see folders in notes. The point is you should select `Folders` section, not `Notes`:

[image]

And in this section, all Outlook data is visible in single tree.

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version of Outlook 365, Notes are available in the left hand icon view, often in More Items.

So notes as they were created are definitely still available.

Open Notes so you can see your Notes in the right hand main Window.  I see them all there.

Now Right Click in this main Notes window and select Sort.  Sort in any order you wish.

So you should be able to see / sort as you wish. I can here in Outlook 365 most recent version.

Microsoft may change the overall view of the Sort as Outlook evolves.

Comment: I can sort, but I need to see subfoders. Not just order, but hierarchy

Comment: I do not think you can build a tree sort. I know what is in my folders, so I can sort and go to the folder I need. What you see is a limitation of the current Outlook sorting.

Comment: I was creating folders for years. Now they just dropped them? Very microsoftish

Comment: To your point in the other answer, I can see what is inside folders, but if a note is outside a folder, I do not create folders inside notes.